# c# Get Active Window Text (causes vshost32.exe has stopped working)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm basically running a Windows Form that get the text of an active window, for example Google Chrome - some text :

My method here:

```
public static String GetActiveWindowText()
{  
        var handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        GetWindowText(handle, sb, 1000);
        return sb.Length == 0 ? "Unhand Window" : sb.ToString();
}
```

for GetForegroundWindow():

```
[DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow()
```

**Note :** When I try on a Notepad or similar program like notepad or blocknote it works perfectly but when I try it on Google Chrome it causes the program to crash vshost32.exe has stopped working.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer, and then mark it as accepted (after the time limit).

Comment: @Bradley Uffner Made it ! , Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED** :

I had to get the Length of the Text First :

```
public static String GetActiveWindowText()
{

    var handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(handle); // Length First
    var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);
    GetWindowText(handle, sb, sb.Capacity);
    return sb.Length == 0 ? "Unhand Window" : sb.ToString();

}
```

GetWindowTextLength is :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError= true, CharSet= CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern Int32 GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
```